# Как использовать LINQ Contains совместно с массивом или списком содержащим строки

Tags: c#, linq

Необходимо из базы данных выбрать совпадения с массивом строк

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
var obj = from ee in db.Searchs where ee.words.Contains(sstr) select ee;
```

где sstr - массив со строками либо `List<string>`.

Подскажите, как сделать правильно?

Буду благодарен и решению через лямбда выражение.

Comment: стоит добавить пример входных и выходных данных

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj = from ee in db.Searchs
          where sstr.All(word => ee.words.Contains(word))
          select ee;
```

Comment: Данный вариант работает, но очень медленно. Если я не ошибаюсь то тут получается цикл в цикле, где внутренний цикл - перебор строк в базе данных. У меня там около 20к строк. Получается очень медленно. Есть ли налог SQL запроса 'WHERE IN (Value1,Value2)', где вместо '(Value1,Value2)', можно подставить массив или 'List<string>'?

Comment: @Frol4ic, а как еще можно узнать содержатся ли строки в массиве не перебрав их?
Скажите какую структуру меет БД. Что собой представляет Searchs. И как работаете с БД

Comment: Структура - выборка из 1 таблицы (EF + Linq). Делаю поисковик текстов песен из БД. Строка запроса разбивается на фразы, фразы заносятся в массив sstr[]. Ищу способ выборки за 1 проход из БД. Я так понимаю, что SQL запрос 'WHERE IN (Value1,Value2)   делает выборку за 1 проход. Searchs - это таблица БД, содержащая тексты песен  + ID

Comment: Попробовал на более мощном компьютере. Вроде скорость норм. Спасибо за ответы! Но если есть варианты еще - буду рад...

Comment: Еще 1 вопрос вдогонку. Как вместо массива вставить List[string]? Уже сам разобрался. Спасибо.

Comment: @Frol4ic, var sstr = new List<string>() { "Word1", "Word2" }; Или что нужно? Куда вставлять?

Comment: Уже сам разобрался. Спасибо.

Comment: @Frol4ic, пожалуйста :)